# Using Twilio AMD with outbound calls from native Programmable Voice SDK

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm using a the Twilio Programmable Voice SDK to initiate calls from my native apps. I want to be able to use answering machine detection on those calls, but I've struggled to figure out how to accomplish it.

I know AMD can't be initiated through TwiML, but can it also not be initiated through Twilio Programmable SDK?

How do I enable async AMD on calls initiated through a native app with Programmable Voice SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter `"machineDetection" => "Enable"` to detect if the call is received by Answering Machine. Twilio SDK helps you in answering machine detection.

It returns `AnsweredBy` value as soon as it identifies the called party.

You can find more details in documentation [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection)

Comment: Right, this works fine for me through the REST API. But I'm trying to initiate the call through the Programmable Voice SDK (not the REST APIs), and it isn't working.

Comment: AMD only works for calls initiated via the REST API /Calls resource.

Comment: The Programmable Voice SDK is a server side SDK, https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries. I think you mean the JavaScript SDKs aka Twilio Client.

Comment: Yes, I mean the iOS and Android SDKs. So then it's true that there's no possible way to use AMD with these SDKs?

Comment: You could use AMD by generating the outbound call with the REST API, putting the Client that dialled out into a queue to wait (basically the same as the phone ringing), then if the call connects and it's a human, directing it to the queue and connecting with the agent.